# How to use a VPC endpoint to access my S3 bucket list/buckets?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have tried almost everything I could find, but after creating a VPC endpoint:
vpce-xxxx-xxxx.s3.eu-central-1.vpce.amazonaws.com
I cannot access this from the internet. I am only doing this because a customer is using the service, but I cannot for the life of me figure out how to send HTTP requests to the above endpoint and have it respond properly. All connection attempts fail:
"The connection to 'bucket.vpce-xxx-xxxx.s3.eu-central-1.vpce.amazonaws.com' failed. A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed...because connected host has failed to respond"

I tried creating an EC2 instance and connecting with:
aws s3 --region eu-central-1 --endpoint-url https://bucket.vpce-xxx-xxx.s3.eu-ecentral-1.pce.amazonaws.com ls s3://mybucketname
However that also times out. Is there any guide or anything to minimally configure a VPC endpoint so I can access it from the internet? I would appreciate any help and give out all necessary details.

Comment: Regarding *"I cannot access this from the internet"* - no idea what you mean with that. Your VPC endpoint cannot be used "from the internet", they can be used from within your VPC.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A VPC endpoint is normally accompanied by entries in the routing table(s) of the subnet(s) of the VPC it belongs to. Those route tables use prefix lists to route all requests towards S3 in the same region to the VPC endpoint instead of other possible routes.

That means your application does not need to do *anything* to make use of the VPC endpoint, specifically you should **not** try anything like `https://bucket.vpce-xxx-xxx.s3.eu-ecentral-1.pce.amazonaws.com` (not sure where you got that URL from), **just do a completely regular `aws s3 ls s3://mybucketname`**.

*"Is there any guide or anything to minimally configure a VPC endpoint so I can access it from the internet"* - I doubt it. That is not what VPC endpoints are to be used for. They are for requests from your VPC to AWS services, not Internet -> Anywhere.

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply, using the URL was given as an example here (underneath the AWS CLI examples):
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/privatelink-interface-endpoints.html
I also found it being used in this example of using the AWS SDK:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/code-samples/latest/catalog/javav2-s3-src-main-java-com-example-s3-VPCS3Example.java.html
I created a similar one as shown above following the doc. Is it not possible to send a request from my local machine to this point to access AWS S3 Services? Like using "https://s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/"

Comment: @AdamWhite you are least missing a `v` as part of the `.vpce.` part of the `aws cli` snippet you shared. I was referring to gateway endpoint in my answer, not interface endpoints, I would consider the former to be the default if available. Now regardless of that fact what I said regarding internet reachability remains the same: you need to inside the VPC to use VPC endpoints. *"These endpoints are directly accessible from applications that are on premises over VPN and AWS Direct Connect, or in a different AWS Region over VPC peering."*.

Comment: @AdamWhite you can only connect to them from your local machine if you have a VPN connection and routing set up such that your local machine "enters" the VPC. (wrong terminology, but still...)

Comment: Thank you very much. Sorry for taking your time, I have little experience with AWS services. Would "applications" include any EC2 instances in the same region? So, should I be able to connect with the above AWS Cli example, or do I need to make any particular configurations for it to be possible, or is it simply impossible?
Thank you for noticing the 'v' but that seems to be a question typo on my part. Following command times out if executed in the EC2 instance:
"aws s3 --region eu-central-1 --endpoint-url https://bucket.vpce-xxx-xxx.s3.eu-central-1.vpce.amazonaws.com ls s3://mybucketname"

Comment: @AdamWhite in general the command from an EC2 instance should work, as long as the instance is in the same VPC and is correctly set up. Debugging issues is quite difficult, especially in a remote setting if it is not "my" VPC and instance. E.g. checking it the name resolution works, if you internet connectivity, if you can use gateway endpoints for other services, ... Did you follow https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/privatelink/create-interface-endpoint.html to craete the endpoint?

Comment: I finally got it working from inside an EC2 instance after configuring everything from scratch, thank you very much for all the answers. They helped a lot to understand the purpose of everything.

Comment: Dang
U saved my time 